# Grabbing selective code from external HTML file with PHP

Tags: php, html, design-patterns

I am beginning to create a pattern library from [BareBones](http://barebones.paulrobertlloyd.com/_patterns.php). It uses PHP to pull in external HTML files to create the different sections. I would like to be able to have a heading and description for each section. BareBones seems to use a separate text file for the usage descriptions, which I could do for the heading too. This would mean I would have 3 files for each section though. Is there a better way to do this? Some thoughts I had, but haven't been able to figure out are:

- Have heading as commented out first line of HTML file and then pull the first line via PHP
- Create a variable in the HTML doc somehow and use it to store the heading and call it from the main file. I think to do this I would need to make all of the snippets PHP files though.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Most people use XML or JSON for this purpose.  For XML, consult http://us3.php.net/simplexml which is fairly easy to understand.  I guess I should also ask, are you pulling data from your own site or another?  A lot of sites have RSS feeds featuring XML.

Comment: @Devon, that could work, but I think using PHP for all of it is possible and probably easiest. I found a solution via the A List Apart Pattern Library that I think will work for me.

Comment: my point was that most don't grab HTML.  XML/JSON makes it much easier to grab content and most sites offer RSS feeds featuring XML.  With simplexml, you can choose which XML node you want and then manipulate it with PHP.